# ttk treeview get tags

Tags: python-2.7, treeview, ttk

Hello i try to get the tags attribute
i have this

```
def treeview(self):
    w = self.widget
    curItem = w.focus()
    print w.item(curItem)

lisswidget = ttk.Treeview(photoFrame)
lisswidget.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", treeview)
lisswidget.insert('', 'end', "", open=True, image=IMG, tags="MyTags")
```

The console return :

```
{'text': '', 'image': [u'pyimage9'], 'values': '', 'open': 1, 'tags': ['MyTags']}
```

How i can extract tags ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it, it's a dictionnary so i do like this :

```
print w.item(curItem)['tags']
```

Comment: tv.item(iid, tag=tv.item(iid, 'tag') + ('detach',)) Python 3.9 Debian